# Exclude CSS class form element in WordPress site

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to exclude "wp-dark-mode-ignore" class from the button class in WordPress?

```html
<button type="button" class="bookingbutton2 wp-dark-mode-ignore" style="">
    <span>Reserve Now</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/);

```js
$('.bookingbutton2').removeClass('wp-dark-mode-ignore');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="bookingbutton2 wp-dark-mode-ignore" style="">
    <span>Reserve Now</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Its working....cheers. I add this code line into appearance>customize>customJs in my WordPress site jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.bookingbutton2').removeClass('wp-dark-mode-ignore');
})